# To change Android Default Font Size

Tags: android, fonts, size

Can anyone please tell me where exactly the Default Text Font size is set in the android framework.When I change the font size using Spare Parts package and reboot my android device, the font size sets to Normal style by default.But I want it to be Extremely Large by default.

Thanks,
Riyaz

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to set font size for the whole phone. Try going to

```
Settings (Phone) > Accessibility.
```

Choose `Large Text` there.

NOTE: I am assuming you just want the font for the phone and not via an app.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but I don't have any font size setting in Settings (Phone) > Accessibility. Am using Android 2.3.4 GingerBread

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a default font size. You can define a theme, and define a font size in your theme. You can read about defining themes and styles in the android developer reference documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.The Spare Parts package does change the system wide font size except that when the device is restarted it sets back to Normal font size.

Answer (score 0):

You can change font size, style etc in your application, but not for whole device. To do that i guess you need to root your phone and provide custom fonts with specified font size in it.

Answer (score 0):

For andriod 2.3.5 go to SMS click on Menu-> Settings scroll down until you see Font Setting and select Font Size Setting

Comment: I have 2.3.6, and I see no such option.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://recombu.com/mobile/article/changing-font-size_M18292.html there is no native option for that, up to Android 3.0.

You have to install some third party app. "Big Font" appears to be a popular one.