# how to change default font size in android?

Tags: android, font-size

I am working on **font related application in which I need to change the system font size**. I couldn't find any examples in google. If anybody have experience in accessing system font please help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

I tried the below code, but it's not working.

```
Settings.System.putFloat(getBaseContext().getContentResolver(),
                        Settings.System.FONT_SCALE, (float) 1.3);
```

Comment: add android:textSize="18sp" to the text view or whatever view you are referencing in xml to increase the font size?

Comment: He wants to change the system setting's font size not his app's font size

Comment: yes, Orphamiel. I want to change the system's font..not textview or any particular application. Is there any intents to font configuration

Comment: I don't think that will be possible until you have root access of the device and to get a root access, device must be rooted first.

Comment: This is not possible AFAIK without needing root:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10943154/to-change-android-default-font-size

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1152710

It is however possible to read the font size with (but I think you already know) :
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#FONT_SCALE

Comment: yes, I am able to read the font size. Just have a look at BigFont app app in google play. I think this is possible without rooting.Thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: In that application, read the description, where they have mentioned `It may not work for all devices. Please try it and let me know (Settings > App log) if it does not work on your device.
Starting from Android 4.2, this app only works on rooted devices due to Android disables 3rd party apps to change system UI configuration (color, font) unless you are using a rooted phone.`

Answer (score 0):

Well, after searching a lot, I found this [question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/4bJuu7tP1_Y), in which, Romain Guy has mentioned that it is not possible.

As I also mentioned in my comment up there, for this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.bfont&hl=en) you are referring to, they also have mentioned in the description that `It may not work for all devices. Please try it and let me know (Settings > App log) if it does not work on your device.
Starting from Android 4.2, this app only works on rooted devices due to Android disables 3rd party apps to change system UI configuration (color, font) unless you are using a rooted phone.`

**I found another topic on [here](http://wiki.gpii.net/index.php/Android_General_Configuration), check if that helps you**.

Comment: Hello mANDROID,  Thank you very much for your valuable information.